# Why is my delete_all method returning a list with a random memory location in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-toplevel

So, I'm trying to delete all elements where Y is a.  It seems to work but the problem I'm getting is that it is returning the wrong thing.  This the result of my return.

```
Result = [b, c, d|_G1355]
```

This is my code so far.

```
mydelete_all([],Y,Result).
mydelete_all([X|T], Y, [X|Result]):-
       X \= Y,
       mydelete_all(T, Y, Result).
mydelete_all([ThowAway|Tail], Y, Result):-
       mydelete_all(Tail, Y, Result).
```

Comment: That's not a random memory location, it's just a variable you didn't give a name to. In the future, you should include the call *and* the result, so we can reproduce it more easily. Change your first predicate to `mydelete_all([], _, [])` and read up on singleton variable warnings! They are **not** ignorable warnings!

Comment: oh okay, i was wondering what that was.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DanielLyons: Actualy, that number is pretty random.

Comment: @DanielLyons. I can't stand anonymous variables like `_G1355`... How about you?

Comment: @repeat, false if you guys think that's a memory location, you've been away from C for too long. :)

Comment: @repeat I don't know what an esper is. Anyway, I think you're more likely to confuse a new user with this "fun fact" than illuminate.

Comment: @DanielLyons. (1) An ESPer is a person who has extrasensory perceptions. (2) You're right. I will remove my previous comment. (3) Still I wonder why you suggested that we "think it's a memory location". (4) Getting back to variable names like `_G1355`: To me, names like this are more than mildly annoying. Some Prolog systems (e.g. SICStus) basically do the Right Thing and use names like `_A`, `_B` etc when portraying internal existentially quantified variables. What's your stance on this?

Comment: @repeat The title of the question is "Why is my delete_all method returning a list with a random memory location in prolog?" so that's why I said "It's not a random memory location" and then you and false said "it is random!" to which I said, "yeah, but it isn't a memory location"… this is all very tedious, let's drop it and get back to helping people learn Prolog! :)

Comment: @DanielLyons. Right! I tend to digress;) Thanks for focussing!

Answer (score 3):

First, when you loaded your program, you got a warning or two about the variables `Y`, `Result` and `ThowAway`.  Such warnings should be removed, before you run your program.

Your concrete query was

```
?- mydelete_all([a,b,c,d],a,Result).
```

The toplevel SWI-Prolog showed you this with a randomly named variable. Actually, in your version of SWI-Prolog that is as you have guessed more or less the memory location. Newer versions of SWI show a non-reproducible number instead — and without a `G`.

Other systems give more readable names, as e.g. SICStus or GNU.

So what does this answer

```
Result = [b,c,d|_A]
```

actually mean? It comprises all lists that start with `b`,`c`,`d`.  So `[b,c,d]`, but also `[b,c,d,a]` are solutions. Didn't you want to delete all occurrences of `a`, and now one of the solutions for `Result` contains `a` again?

But the situation is worse. Type `;` to get further solutions:

```
?- mydelete_all([a,b,c,d],a,Result).
   Result = [b,c,d|_A]
;  Result = [b,c|_A]
;  Result = [b,d|_A]
;  Result = [b|_A]
;  Result = [c,d|_A]
;  Result = [c|_A]
;  Result = [d|_A]
;  false.
```

Even worse:

```
?- mydelete_all([a],a,[a]).
   true.
?- mydelete_all([],a,[a]).
   true.
```

This last query can only use your fact. So this fact is way too general.  Another error is `X \= Y` replace it by `dif(X, Y)`. And then the last rule!